# VSTS Build - npm version minor command does not commit changes to GitHub

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, npm-version

I'm trying to build the CI/CD Pipeline for my project in VSTS.  The tests, build and deployment flow is all fine and working as expected.

But I couldn't manage to commit the auto increased version number in the package.json to the github repo.

My steps on the VSTS agent are as per this image.
[image]

I wrote the following npm scripts in **Increase Version Number** step to increase the minor version number.

```
git config user.email "ttcgabc123@gmail.com"
git config user.name "ttcg"

npm version minor

git commit
git push origin master --tags
```

It does increase the version number from 0.2.0 to 0.3.0 but, it doesn't push the changes made back to my github repo and I couldn't manage to commit/push these changes.

Please see the output of the above step in VSTS build.  On line no. 12, you can see the new version number.

[image]

I tried to use `git remote add origin https://github.com/ttcg/react-workout-diary.git`, but it shows the error message `fatal: remote origin already exists.`

Could you please advise me how can I automate to increase the version number in my CI/CD pipeline?

Comment: git push origin master --tags would only push the tags, what happens if you change it to 'git push origin master' ? Also, if you have this setup as a continuous integration build, you may end up in a never ending loop of builds since every time a build runs, you're updating the branch that triggers the build. If you're just trying to have a unique package id, then you might want to try to use a build variable (build number or build id) in the 3rd position of your version.

Comment: There is no difference without --tags.  It looks like I need to run that command manually on the dev machine to increase the version before commiting/pushing to the repo to prevent the loop or use the build number as you suggested.  Could you please provide the good resource for that build number?

Comment: You could likely use BuildID or Rev:.r depending on how you're doing your builds/branching/versioning. These are pipeline variables, so you may need to pass them as command line arguments to your package process or use an additional task or custom script. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/options?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml